# Trying to count a particular character in an excel sheet and the formula needs to change with each row

Tags: google-spreadsheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69FLl.png)

Is there any way to change the formula based on the cell the formula is in, for example. If the formula is in the 5th row. I'd like it to count the occurances of the character in that particular row.

Comment: Hi. Your question needs more work. First you mention "excel sheet" in the title but then you use "google-spreadsheets" as tag. Which are you using? Also, spreadsheets naturally change formula based on the cell. The screenshot you posted suggests row 8 is pointing at row 5 but it is not clear if this is what you expect or not. If you expand on what you are trying to achieve somebody may be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, I might have made a noob mistake about mentioning excel. I'm trying to use the CountIF formula to count the number of time "P" occurs in a specific range. I'd like the range to change according to the cell the formula is in.

For example in row 5 , the formula would be =COUNTIF(E5:5,"P") and in row 6 it would be =COUNTIF(E6:6,"P").

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of occurrences of ***P*** in the cells of column **C**, row by row, in **A1** enter:

```
=len(C1)-len(substitute(C1,"P",""))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

As you see, cell **C4** has three **P**'s, so *3* is returned.